# Running the django migrations one by one

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have django migrations on production server until 0102_auto.
Now in my development server i have 13 more and number is 0115_auto in dev server.
Tomorrow i will carry all files to production server. Also i will carry models.py , views.py and templates to production server. Normally i run migrate on production server and it migrates all new 13 migrations. But this time i want to run migrations one by one to have more control. Because i had some issues on test server.

Is it possible to run these 13 new migrations one by one manually, one after another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to automate the migrations without typing them manually everytime, you can create a `bash` script, that handles the migrations order for you. Here is an example:

**migrations.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

APP='my_app_name'
# Here list the migration's files order
LIST=( '0001 0002 0003 0004' )

for i in $LIST; do
    echo 'Applying migration' $i
    python manage.py migrate $(echo $APP) $(echo $i)
done
```

Then place yourself in the same level as `manage.py` and run:

```
$> sh migrations.sh
```

It will output something like this:

```
Applying migration 0001
Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0001_initial, from my_app_name
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  ...
```

For more informations, visit [Django documentation: migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#migrate)

Comment: What if you don't have multiple migrations?